# Implementation of NETIQ IDAM LDAP using JAVA

Tags: java, ldap, netiq

We are trying to integrating the LDPA authentication using java technology but unable to connect the IDAM-NETIQ server while using as below that code,

parameter details,

```
    INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    PROVIDER_URL, "ldap:// IP ADDRESS :10389");
    SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN=Testnetiq.O=IBOM_test");
    SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "PASSWORD");

package com.test.poc;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap:// ldap ip :10389");
    props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN=Testnetiq.O=IBOM_test");
    props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "Wipro@123");

    InitialDirContext context = new InitialDirContext(props);

    SearchControls ctrls = new SearchControls();
    ctrls.setReturningAttributes(new String[] { "givenName", "sn", "memberOf" });
    ctrls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

    NamingEnumeration<javax.naming.directory.SearchResult> answers = context.search("o=IBOM_test",
            "(uid=" + "Test123" + ")", ctrls);
    javax.naming.directory.SearchResult result = answers.nextElement();
    String user = result.getNameInNamespace();

    try {
        props = new Properties();
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://ldap ip :10389");
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user);
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "Test@123");

        context = new InitialDirContext(props);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("false");
        }
        System.out.println("True");
    }

}
```

while accessing we are getting error as below,

> err] javax.naming.AuthenticationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error
>   code 13 - Confidentiality Required] [err]   at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3127) [err]   at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3082) [err]
>   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2883)
>   [err]   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2797) [err] 
>   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.(LdapCtx.java:319) [err]   at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:192)
>   [err]   at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:210)
>   [err]   at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:153)
>   [err]   at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:83)
>   [err]   at
>   org.apache.aries.jndi.ContextHelper.getInitialContextUsingBuilder(ContextHelper.java:244)
>   [err]   at [internal classes] [err]   at
>   javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
>   [err]   at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
>   [err]   at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)

What the problem is our java code or LDAP server?

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace indicates that your LDAP server requires TLS/SSL (LDAP: error code 13 - Confidentiality Required).

Try connecting to the LDAPS port instead.

Usually it's 636.

In your case, since you are trying to connect on port 10389 it might be 10636.

You will probably need to import the Organizational CA certificate into your Java keystore as well to be able to connect successfully.

These are the instructions for exporting the certificate using iManager.

To export the Organizational CA's self-signed certificate:

```
Launch iManager.

Log in to the eDirectory tree as an administrator with the appropriate rights.

To view the appropriate rights for this task, see Entry Rights Needed to Perform Tasks.

On the Roles and Tasks menu, click NetIQ Certificate Server > Configure Certificate Authority.

This brings up the property pages for the Organizational CA, which include a General page, a CRL page, a Certificates page, and other eDirectory-related pages.

Click Certificates, then select the self-signed certificate.

Click Export and follow the prompts to export the certificate.

This starts the Certificate Export Wizard. Ensure the Export private key check box is not selected (does not have a check mark).

Click Finish.
```

You can find that information here: https://www.netiq.com/documentation/edirectory-91/edir_admin/data/b1j4tpo3.html#b1j4tu55

Comment: hi ctrls.setReturningAttributes(new String[] { "givenName", "sn", "memberOf" }); here givenName is what exactly . we have to parse the parameters

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. The givenName is the name of an attribute in the directory servers schema. It's somebody's first name. Check the LDAP RFC if in doubt: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4519#section-2.12

Comment: what is Organizational CA certificate?  where i have to get it. is it provide from LDAP server side or we have to export the certificate